# How to color a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, colors

I have a matrix in matlab of the following form:

```
A=[1 1 1 -1 -1
   0 1 0  1  0
   0 1 1  1  1 
   2 2 0  1  2
   2 2 2  2 -1]
```

This matrix represents a map in the plane. Every A(i, j) is a cell in this map. I want to give color to each cell according to its number. So:

```
If(A(i, j)<=0)
   color(A(i, j)) with black    
Elseif(A(i, j)==k)
   color(A(i, j)) with color k other than black
end
```

How to do this in matlab? Any suggestions please?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. What are you trying to do with this matrix? What do you mean by "color"? Are you trying to display this matrix using a function like "imshow"?

Comment: From the matrix A of size NxN, I associate a map with the same size of A, i.e., a grid of size NxN. I want to give color to each cell in this grid.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. How to change the default color used by imagesc(A) ?

Comment: Try `colormap`. Examples: `colormap hsv`,  `colormap hot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a number of colours that you want using **hsv** or manually.

```
 hsv(3)

ans =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
```

Then use **colormap** to specify the color map.

```
colormap(hsv(3))
```

and then use **imagesc**

```
imagesc(A)
```

[image]

If you want to specify the colour also it is easy:

```
a = hsv(3)
a(1,:) = 1;   % make the first color white
a(3,:) = 0;   % make the last color black

a =

     1     1     1
     0     1     0
     0     0     0

colormap(a)
imagesc(A)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If I wnat to define black for any value less or equal to 0. blue to 1. red to 2. How to do this ?